# get child assembly name that inheriting custom class from the inherited assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, .net-assembly

I have two assembly
one contain some classes I want to use them in another assembly's
and the other is inhering a class from the first assembly

from the original class in the first assembly I need to know the name of the assembly that try to inherit my class

Comment: Why? That's almost always a design smell. Your base class should not care who inherits it. Anyway see GetType().

Comment: OK , can you give me another solution for my task , for example I can add a string property in the original class and when other assembly's create new instance from the original class automatic they set this string property to their names , can I do that ??

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but unless you make a very good case for why you think you need that, I'm not going to explain it. **Your base class should not care who inherits it**.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is storing some strings values comes from all availabe plugs in my application and I want to make sure those string not conflicted with each other .

Comment: What @CodeCaster is getting at is that the fact that your base class needs to know anything about your derived classes is an indicator of a poor design overall.  Consider redesigning at a higher level.

Comment: That makes little sense given the context. It should not be solved in the base class. Solve it in the "plugin container" or whatever class's responsibility it is to load and manage the plugins.

Comment: @emadalden -- You're mixing up responsibilities.  Don't confuse "has-a" relationships (like a class that contains a collection of uniquely-named plugins) with "is-a" relationships (like classes that derive from other classes).  You're torturing object oriented principals by doing so.

Comment: OK , I'm going to make another inheritance class in each assembly I want to use the original class and then I will set a property to tell the inheritance dll name , thanks for help .

Comment: @emadalden -- no, I think you've missed the point entirely.

Comment: it's hard to me to explain for you what I'm trying to do ( my English language not perfect ) , but at least I know that it's possible to do my task only from the main assembly